# How to update a list element that uses tuple?

Tags: c#, tuples

I have the following list declared to contain a tuple:

```
private List<Tuple<string, string, int>> cellsChanges;
```

Then I have a method in where that if data exists then I will need to update data with new values:

```
private void AddCellChanges(object name, object value, int type)
{
    var isItemExists = cellsChanges.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Item1 == (string)name && a.Item2 == (string)value);
    if (isItemExists == null)
    {
        cellsChanges.Add(new Tuple<string, string, int>((string)name, (string)value, type));
    }
    else
    {
        var getIndex = cellsChanges.IndexOf(isItemExists);
        // Update Tuple
    }
}
```

How can I update list element that uses tuple. for example I would like to update the first and the second items.

Comment: Tuples are immutable. Create a new instance and assign it to that index.

Comment: cellsChanges[0]= new Tuple<string, string, int>((string)name, (string)value, type)

Comment: Okay I see so creating new instance with specifying the index will overrides the existing one thanks

Comment: @moe1792 it will not override existing one, it will create another tuple that you will use.

Comment: Yes but what I am looking for is to override an existing one. therefore, I did use getIndex so my question will it be possible to override an existing one or not. and if yes how.